# Append declared language to html?

Tags: jquery, html, css, append, lang

How could I add 'lang="en"' to the end of my opening html tag? I can't just write it in there manually as I don't have access to it (ecommerce package), but I'd like to be able to declare the site language somehow.

Comment: For what purpose? If it's for SEO, the javascript solutions don't work.

Comment: It is for seo, yes. Why would they not work?

Comment: Because search engines don't run the JavaScript. This would only be helpful for changing CSS styles depending on language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the attributes of any element using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('html').attr('lang','en');
```

With plain JS, you can also access the `<html>` element with the `documentElement`:

```
document.documentElement.lang = 'en';
```

Comment: For future readers, this does NOT work for SEO purposes as you should assume that the crawler bots do not do JavaScript. For all they know, the `lang` still isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in JavaScript but I'm not sure whether it would be useful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('lang', 'en')
} catch(e) { };
</script>
```

You would be best advised to modify the template from the ecommerce package if possible.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution that 4castle has is fully correct it does not serve the purpose of improving the SEO :(

The reason for this is that when Google crawls your site it just looks at the sites HTML markup without running any JS. It simply never gets to see the changed `lang` attribute.

As Owen points out, it's better to try to modify the template files (if the eCom-pack doesn't have a feature where the attribute can be set in some kind of admin interface?).

Comment: It does not, and I have no access to it at all.

Comment: In that case I can only think of one more solution: Many services and package providers are pretty keen on their customers satisfaction, especially if they are a smaller company. You could try to check with their tech department if they could help you out with a custom solution! :)